# Database of wikipedia ulrs of Computer Category

Tags: search-engine, mediawiki, wikipedia

We are building a vertical search engine which will search on computer domain. So, we want all  URLs of Wikipedia which belong to computer category. Is there any such database available? If not how can we fetch all URLs from Wikipedia belonging to Computer category? We need only URLs not complete webpages.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any such database available?

You can try at http://dbpedia.org.

> how can we fetch all URLs from Wikipedia belonging to Computer category?

Check the [Categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers). You will however need to recursively traverse the [subcategories](http://toolserver.org/~dapete/catgraph/graph.php?lang=en&wiki=wikipedia&cat=Computers&sub=1&format=svg&links=graph), and filter out a lot pages manually.

Comment: Note that there is nothing that prevent MediaWiki categories from going into loops, like `Cat:A`<`Cat:B`<`Cat:A`, and it is also likely, as @Bergi points out, that you will find *a lot* of unrelated categories and pages in the category tree, and also pages from other namespaces, such as templates.

Comment: You will, for instance, find `aluminum polymer composite`, Australian artist `Simon Penny` and [a template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Transformers) for transformer toys in that tree.

Comment: Looking at articles that are part of [WikiProject Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Computing) might be a better choice: [Category:All Computing articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:All_Computing_articles).